# Pivot table horizontal to vertical between two tables mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I have a Q&A for which below is my table structure

select * from tbl_test_question;

```
q_id |   que          | opt1  |   opt2 |   opt3 |   opt4 |   ans
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1   |  what is this? |  cat  |   dog  |   owl  |   cow  |   opt2
 2   |  what is that? |  man  |   pig  |   bat  |   rat  |   opt4
 3   |  who is this?  |  ice  |   flea |   dirt |   lion |   opt1
 4   |  who is that?  |  goat |   meat |   kid  |   gin  |   opt3
```

select * from tbl_user_answer

```
 uid |   qid |   submit_ans |   correct_ans
-------------------------------------------------
  1  |    1  |     opt2     |       opt2
  1  |    2  |     opt3     |       opt4
  1  |    3  |     opt4     |       opt1 
  1  |    4  |     opt1     |       opt3
```

Joining both I would like my result to look like this.

```
qid  |  submit_ans |  submittext |  correct_ans |  correcttext
-------------------------------------------------------------
 1   |     opt2    |    dog      |     opt2     |     dog             
 2   |     opt3    |    bat      |     opt4     |     rat                  
 3   |     opt4    |   lion      |     opt1     |     ice                  
 4   |     opt1    |   goat      |     opt3     |     kid
```

I have not been able to think of any way to get it to look like this. I have never done pivot before. Is there a query by which I could get the result?

Comment: If you can normalise `tbl_test_question` by adding another table, this will be so much easier to achieve.

Comment: @halfer Pardon me. I dont understand what you meant by normalise..

Comment: There is a natural relationship between question and options, which is called "one to many". To represent this in your database, you would have a question table and a question option table i.e. one question can have many options. Since one question can have one answer (in this design) you would continue to store `ans` in the question and not against each option. The process of converting a database to this better format is called "normalisation".

Comment: If you can make this change then the SQL to do what you want is much simplified, and will work even if you want to add questions with less or more than four options. However, whether you can do this depends on how complicated it is to change your application code.

Comment: If you don't understand 'normalise', I strongly suggest you fix that first. It's the fundamental concept of relational databases. For some (like me) it's a little tricky to get to grips with (and, to be fair, there is tons of authoritative-sounding rubbish out there on the subject). Nevertheless, it's essential if you want to use an RDBMS.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I actually did it this way cos the people who are going add the data in `tbl_test_question` were non-technical and they wanted all in one table itself.

Comment: The people adding the data need know nothing about the underlying structure - just like on posting on Facebook, etc.

Comment: @adbury: your client/employer is asking you to make poor quality design choices that may hurt performance or maintainability in the future. If this system is business critical you may wish to encourage them to get an advisor who can help them get to a more maintainable code state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables and use CASE expressions like this:

```
select
  q.q_id qid, u.submit_ans submit_ans,
  case u.submit_ans
    when 'opt1' then q.opt1
    when 'opt2' then q.opt2
    when 'opt3' then q.opt3
    when 'opt4' then q.opt4
  end submit_text,
  u.correct_ans,
    case u.correct_ans
    when 'opt1' then q.opt1
    when 'opt2' then q.opt2
    when 'opt3' then q.opt3
    when 'opt4' then q.opt4
  end correcttext
from tbl_test_question q inner join tbl_user_answer u
on u.qid = q.q_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=3b68df88ae291c0ac04ec438a33380f9).
Results:

```
> qid | submit_ans | submit_text | correct_ans | correcttext
> --: | :--------- | :---------- | :---------- | :----------
>   1 | opt2       | dog         | opt2        | dog        
>   2 | opt3       | bat         | opt4        | rat        
>   3 | opt4       | lion        | opt1        | ice        
>   4 | opt1       | goat        | opt3        | kid
```

Comment: @forpas  This seems to work for me. I find changing the structure too much work as a lot of code has already been done. I will use this and hope additional requirements dont pop up in future. Thank you very much.

Comment: @adbury Let's hope you don't come to regret that choice!! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Too long and clever for a comment...

While not pretending to be a definitive solution, here is an example of a normalised schema:

```
tbl_test_question:

+------+---------------+
| q_id | question      |
+------+---------------+
|    1 | what is this? | 
|    2 | what is that? | 
|    3 | who is this?  | 
|    4 | who is that?  | 
+------+---------------+

tbl_user_answer:

+------+--------+-------+---------+
| q_id | option | value | correct |
+------+--------+-------+---------+
|    1 |      1 | cat   |       0 | 
|    2 |      1 | man   |       1 |
|    3 |      1 | ice   |       0 | 
|    4 |      1 | goat  |       0 | 
|    1 |      2 | dog   |       0 |  
|    2 |      2 | pig   |       0 | 
|    3 |      2 | flea  |       0 |  
|    4 |      2 | meat  |       1 |
|    1 |      3 | owl   |       0 |
|    2 |      3 | bat   |       0 | 
|    3 |      3 | dirt  |       0 |  
|    4 |      3 | kid   |       0 | 
|    1 |      4 | cow   |       0 |  
|    2 |      4 | rat   |       0 | 
|    3 |      4 | lion  |       1 |
|    4 |      4 | gin   |       0 |  
+------+--------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. I actually have not studied mysql or any language extensively. I use google for most of my project. I research on a need to know basis only. When I am stuck I look around and If I dont find a solution I post here and hope some kind soul ;-) would help me out. Also I hope I would do better next time.

Comment: I suspect that goes for 80% of contributors to this forum.